# Does full synchronization in Assassin's Creed influence anything?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

Does full synchronization in Assassin's Creed influence anything, like story outcome or abilities that you get or even Easter eggs or dialogs?

Or is there absolutely no point to those bonus objectives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full synchronization doesn't influence anything except the fact that you unlock a new outfit located in the Homestead manor and the achievemenet which gets you a step closer to the premium trophy if you're interested in it.(only in Ps3 or Xbox)

Comment: Also the pure satisfaction of winning history and the internet.

Comment: No for me there is no satisfaction in that^^

Comment: + satisfaction of completing the game, not just playing through the story

Comment: Do you get the outfit after getting 100% sync on every mission? If so I don't see the point of having it, since at the point you will be done with the game.